# Identity Server 4 validate own issued JWTs

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4, openid

Ok, user authenticates and client gets the JWT from my IS4 instance. All that works. Now, for reasons I still cry at nights after being tormented by people who authoritatively claim to know OAuth but do not, the client is sending me the identity token JWT over the wire to an action, and I need to do some work based on the subject in it. I want to minimize the fallout of this decision and prevent a situation where someone plants me a fake token, so I want to validate the JWT to make sure it came from me, that indeed I am the one who issued it. To simplify, I need to act as both the client and the server in the token validation process, while running on the IS4.

Since this is such a violation of OAuth protocol, I am not sure this is supported out of the box, but here comes: is there a way to do this? I even tried to introspect the token, but that requires an authentication context, and I can't seem to get the client credential flow working since I only use openid/profile scopes and they are not supported by the client credential flow (since the user is defined only in JWT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiver of a token should always validate the signature of the token to make sure it came from your IdentityServer. This is usually automatically done by most proper JWT-libraries. The library will download the public-key from your IdentityServer and use it to verify the signature of the token.

If you are using ASP.NET, then the JwtBearer library will do that for you.

Comment: I was actually hoping that something was built in the IS4 itself, I am familiar with the standard client process, just wanted to avoid a round trip through the net layer. But ok, I did this and it works, got jwk_uris keys, repacked them into `SecurityKey`s and used `JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken` from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. Since there is no real answer, I'll accept yours as the closest possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, In .NET the AddJwtBearer only downloads the keys/config from IdentitytServer every 24 hours, so there is no extra call to IdentityServer per incoming access token to the API. However your question is not 100% clear, as no-one can send you a fake token without having a copy of your private key.

Comment: The problem is that I do not use bearer authentication, so its not integrated into pipeline. I am actually being sent the JWT as a POST parameter to a controller action ON the IS4 instance itself (yea, its that weird). So I have to do what AddJwtBearer does to validate the token only I have to do it in the "meat" of the action method. People can send me fake tokens, signed with their own PK, in an attempt to fool my code into accepting it because, by default, tokens in POST body do not get auto-validated. If I do not check the signature, I rely full on "security by obscurity" and thats a nono.

Comment: As for caching, its not a problem, this method will be called maybe like few times a month.

Comment: Actually, JwtBearer can accept tokens from other sources than the authorization header, do explore the code here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L50 :-)

Comment: alternatively, you could pretty easy write a request pipeline middleware that takes the token from the body and adds it as a header to the request, and then pass it to JwtBearer?

Comment: Meh, I think I already wasted far too much time on this.